# Same item, different DPS in game and Auction House

Tags: diablo-iii

So I found this item, and decided to sell it in the Auction House. Why would it show a different DPS in said Auction House when compared to in game?

(599.9 in game, 600.1 in Auction House)

[image: Cropped screenshot showing DPS of 599.9 on a Rare Staff (2-Hand) with 450-750 Damage, 1.00 Attacks per Second, +63-171 Holy Damage, +16% Damage, +104 Dexterity, +215 Vitality, 2.9% of Damage Dealt is Converted to Life]
[image: Cropped screenshot showing DPS of 600.1 on the same item]

Comment: Playing as a wizard, but that shouldn't matter.....should it?

Comment: It seems a bug :)

Comment: Looks like a float rounding bug; sensitive question :x

Comment: Weird, not seen anything like this in game yet. Playing as a Wizard should have no effect on the maths that makes these numbers work so I can only go with it being some bug.

Comment: I agree, it's definitely a floating point error. The DPS should be exactly 600 but since floating point numbers have problems with exact numbers it is slightly off. The direction of the error depends on previous calculations which are probably different ingame and out of game. It most likely won't have any effect on the gameplay though, so i'd say report and forget.

Answer (score 2):

I know that i have on several occasions seen similar changes in the DPS on weapons and they have been due to skills, followers, or gems ***when the item is equipped***.  If this is occurring on an item in your inventory, then it is most likely a bug and i would report it to Blizzard.

Comment: I also recently noticed that the modified DPS of a weapon and the base DPS of a weapon are both shown on the AH screen.  The column with DPS shows the base amount and the tooltip shows the modified amount (if there is a gem in it or something.)  Sorting on the column sorts by base DPS i believe...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other items equipped that either give +damage or +speed attack?  When looking at an item on the Auction house, it calculates the dps based on that weapon alone.  But when you look at an item after you purchase it, it takes account of what you currently have equipped and applies any additional modifiers if applicable to that item as well (+attack speed rings/amulets/gloves, +damage rings).

Comment: You're thinking of damage, not the displayed DPS of a weapon

Answer (score -2):

Something I should point out since people are saying that this is a "bug in the DPS  calculation";

The most logical way to program this would be to use the same function that works out the dps in game, I have no clue how they coded the game, but neither do you guys.

It might not be a "bug", it might be the actual DPS calculation the games uses. I guess you could call it a "bug" because it is not what you expect, but if this is the actual dps, then it's not a bug.

Comment: The game doesn't actually calculate anything off of 'dps' as an actual value anyway. Game calculations are based on minimum damage, max damage, and weapon speed.

Comment: Seeing things like this is a common occurrence with floating point operations.  How can it not be a bug if the *same* item is showing two different DPS values?

Comment: ^^not true, the game calculates spell damage based on dps

^it's not the same item, we know that all items store in diablos inventory system are stored with their stats, not as some primary key to a referenced item

Comment: If that were true Richard, then you wouldn't attack faster with your spells if you equipped a faster weapon.  LessPop is correct.  This is clearly a bug.  Unless you have a logical explanation as to why the game would report two differnet things.  Don't you think the guy who buys that in the AH is going to be pissed to see his "over 600" weapon go to "under 600"?  This may have no effect in-game but it's a display/text bug.

Comment: @RichardEllicott - This is clearly a bug.